# Saving and Retrieving png from SQLite database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, listview, png

When downloading transparent png images into an imagelist then putting them directly in a listview the quality is high.

But now I'm trying to save the images into a SQLite database and get them back in the same high quality, but with everything I try the quality is very poor.

I tried SQLite field types of IMAGE, CHAR and BLOB and various methods to get the data back out. Is there a best field type?

I tried saving it as a bitmap but I could not find out how to convert it back to a transparent png. Maybe that would work?

This is the last thing I tried with a CHAR field type. When I add it to a imagelist the quality is very poor (dr is the SQLite datarow).

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dr["image"].ToString());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

Can someone please tell me how to save the transparent png as a high quality image in SQLite and get it back out in the same high quality?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I can save to a BMP with this:

```
string base64ImageString = ImageToBase64(imageList1.Images[i], ImageFormat.bmp);
```

But have no idea how to get it back out as a transparent png,

**EDIT**

The real problem is I've lost the transparency. Those parts are now black.

I'm using this but it does not seem to help:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dr["image"].ToString());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);    

using (MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream())
{
  bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: SQLite does not change the contents of blobs. How are you saving the images into the database?

Comment: What is the code of `ImageToBase64`? That method would have something to notice.

Comment: I'm currently using:

string base64ImageString = ImageToBase64(imageList1.Images[i], ImageFormat.Bmp);

Please see my latest EDIT

Answer (score 1):

I was not saving correctly. This got the quality where I need it.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileNames[j]);
FileStream fileStream = fi.OpenRead();
Image img = new Bitmap(fileStream);

string base64ImageString = ImageToBase64(img, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

I still have a problem with transparency but I'll work on it.

Answer (score -1):

My last comment was deleted because I did not provide any answer there. But, I will provide my answer now for future reference, as I fixed my issue by myself. The key is when you are going to save an Image to sqlite, just make sure you are going to save it as PNG, and ofcourse it is transparent then, you can just retrieve it from sqlite as is..

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for the code, just provide necessary code and explain if needed